# Firebase Database catch Promise's error and store in DB

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, promise

My question probably not limited to firebase database only, but my problem happened while i working on the Angular Project that using Firebase Database so i will tag Firebase & Angular as well.

According to the [Firebase Real Time Database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ThenableReference), most of the ThenableReference is returning a Promise.

When i write a basic function like pushing new object to DB or updating an existing object in DB, it will return me a `Promise`, so i can use `then` to perform next action after done the action with DB.

When there is an error (Permission Denied for example), i can make it display on the screen like this:

[image]

But my problem is, I can't figure out how to write the error into DB to log it down.

Below is my code:

```
this.clientService.createClient(this.client).then(data=>{ //when successfully Push object to DB
      this.loggerService.log('success','createClient', this.client, {id:data['key'],msg:'Successfully Create the Client'}, 'add-client') //Log the result into DB
      this.router.navigate(['search-results',data.key,'client-details']) //route user to another page
      this.toastrService.success('','Successfully Create the Client') //display a successful Pop Up message
    },error=>{
      console.log(error) //this is working
      let msg = error.toString()
      this.loggerService.log('error','createClient', this.client, msg, 'add-client') //this is not working
      this.toastrService.error(error,'Failed to create the Client') //this is working like the attached photo
    });
```

Below is my loggerService.log code:

```
log(status,action,req,res:Object,site){
    let object = {
      dtcreate: Date.now(),
      uid:this.currentUser.uid,
      userEmail:this.currentUser.email,
      action:action,
      req:req,
      res:res,
      site:site,
      status:status
    }
    return this.logRef.push(object)
  }
```

**Edited**:

Below is the error for the `console.log(error)`, this is what i wish to log into my DB (Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied).

```
Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at vendor.js:88796
    at exceptionGuard (vendor.js:76410)
    at Repo.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (vendor.js:88787)
    at vendor.js:88564
    at vendor.js:87739
    at PersistentConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (vendor.js:87772)
    at Connection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onDataMessage_ (vendor.js:87057)
    at Connection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (vendor.js:87051)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (vendor.js:86952)
    at WebSocketConnection.push../node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js.WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (vendor.js:86557)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this.loggerService.log('error','createClient', this.client, msg, 'add-client')` - where is this `msg` defined? - your 4th argument is an object in the onResolved code, but it is an undefined variable in the onRejected code

Comment: Share your error..

Comment: @JaromandaX There is a `let msg = error.toString()` below the `console.log(error)`. console.log(error) did show the erro in Chrome console.

Comment: Oh. How embarrassing. I did not see that. Sorry - but does that need to be in an object? or does `this.loggerService.log` accept an object or a string for the 4th argument?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for coming back. I think i have solved my problem, this mostly is because i simulate in the wrong way. In facts, the code di work after i change another way of simulation. Thanks again!

Comment: call the write function inside the failed functions catch and pass in the error obj.???